# Angular 14 NGRX Selector issue

Tags: angular, ngrx

So in my basket store you can see that I have 5 items 2 have an id 0f 4.
[image]

in my reducer, if I use:

```
 on(getBasket, (state, { id }) =>  state.filter((photo) => photo.id !== id)
```

this works as far as it goes in that the item in the basket will be removed which is fine if I only have 1 item of a particular id in the basket otherwise in this scenario the above will remove 2 entries from the basket. So to only remove 1 I need to introduce a selector to obtain the first index position for id 4 in this case (I dont care which one is removed).

So I have attempted to write:

```
export const basketPosition = createSelector(
  ((state: Array<Photo>, { id }: any) => { return state.indexOf(id) })
  )
```

Where state will be basket, and the id would be 4. However The whole statement red lines and I cannot see what is wrong with that statement. it just keeps stating:

> Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 3.

Comment: I believe there are too many parentheses. Can you try the following: export const basketPosition = createSelector(
  (state: Array<Photo>, { id }: any) => state.indexOf(id) 
  )

Comment: @Loop I made the changes as you suggested, but I still receive the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Took me a while but I have figured out how to remove a single item from my basket when I have multiple of the same item.

So I create an action:

```
export const removeFromBasket = createAction('[Basket Component] removeFromBasket', props<{ id: number }>());
```

then I create a reducer:

```
on(removeFromBasket, (state, { id }) => {
    const basketArray = [...state];
    basketArray.splice(state.findIndex(tt => tt.id === id), 1);
    return basketArray;
    }
  ),
```

then in my component I call the reducer :

```
RemoveFromBasket(photo: Photo) {
    this.basketStore.dispatch(removeFromBasket({ id :photo.id }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you providing `state` and `id` to the selector `basketPosition`...? `createSelector()` needs some State in order to select something from it, giving your example, it could be like the following:

```js
export interface Things {
  basket: Basket[];
  selectedPhotos: Photos[];  
}

// selecting a specific data from the state
export const selectBasket = (state: Things) => state.basket;
export const selectPhotos = (state: Things) => state.selectedPhotos;


//from `selectPhotos` data array, return the first element
export const selectOnePhoto = createSelector(selectPhotos, (photos: Photos[]) => photos[0]);

//from the selectBasket data array, return all elements
export const selectAllItems = createSelector(selectBasket, (basket) => basket);
```

If you require to pass an argument to a `selector`, you can provide one (or many) like the following:

```js
export const selectItemById = (id: string) = createSelector(
  selectBasket,
  (basket) => {
   // ... some logic here...   
   return basket.find(b => b.id === id);
  }
)

// calling it from a component

item$!: Observable<Item | undefined>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.item$ = this.store.select(selectBasket('someId'));
}
```

Comment: if I follow your example, as soon as I introduce `selectItemById = (id: string)....` the reference to `import { createSelector } from "@ngrx/store"` red lines